# R heatmaply and pheatmap output

Tags: r, colors, pheatmap, heatmaply

I am using the R `heatmaply` package to produce interactive heatmaps. I like the software, but I would like to get from it the same color output I get using the `pheatmap` package. Therefore, I would like the two commands to produce the same ouput:

```
heatmaply (scale (mtcars))
pheatmap  (scale (mtcars))
```

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks in advance.
Arturo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `formals()` to get the default color argument of `pheatmap()`.

```
formals(pheatmap)$color
# colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(n = 7, name = "RdYlBu")))(100)
```

Then set the color argument of `heatmaply()` to the same one:

```
col <- colorRampPalette(rev(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n = 7, name = "RdYlBu")))(100)
heatmaply(scale(mtcars), colors = col, grid_color = "grey60")
```

- The color function `brewer.pal()` is from the `RColorBrewer` package, so you need to install and load it with `::` or `library()` in advance.
- `grid_color` in `heatmaply()` is corresponding to `border_color` in `pheatmap()`.