# Clustering in pheatmap and heatmaply R packages

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, pheatmap, heatmaply

I am using the R heatmaply package to produce interactive heatmaps. I like the software, but I would like to get from it the same clustering (ordering of rows and columns) I get using the pheatmap package. Therefore, I would like the two commands to produce the same ouput:

```
heatmaply (scale (mtcars))
pheatmap  (scale (mtcars))
```

Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance. Arturo

P.S. I recently asked another similar question about the color output, i.e., not clustering,  output, that was brilliantly answered here: [R heatmaply and pheatmap output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61931334/r-heatmaply-and-pheatmap-output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution to order columns and rows of `heatmaply` as in `pheatmap`:

```
phtmap <- pheatmap(scale(mtcars))
heatmaply(scale(mtcars), Rowv=phtmap[[1]], Colv=phtmap[[2]], revC=TRUE)
```

The ouput of `pheatmap`
[image]

and the output of `heatmaply`
[image]

Comment: Nice. Thank you!