# Using heatmaply dendrogram sorting in pheatmap

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, pheatmap, heatmaply

Is there a way of using the dendrogram clustering method used in the `heatmaply` package and to apply it to a heatmap produced by the `pheatmap` package? Basically the opposite to what was asked here: [Clustering in pheatmap and heatmaply R packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61935135/clustering-in-pheatmap-and-heatmaply-r-packages)

I usually see better clustering of my data when I use `heatmaply` over `pheatmap`. However, I do not always want to use an interactive plot. The `heatmaply::ggheatmap` function does not work properly for me since I have have `col_side_colors` and the annotation gets in the way of the dendrogram. It just looks very messy. So I use `pheatmap` instead.

Maybe someone can help with my question.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(pheatmap)
library(heatmaply)
library(seriation)
library(dendextend)

# A dataset    
x <- scale(mtcars)

# Interactive heatmap
p <- heatmaply(x)
print(p)

# The dendrogram for rows
dst <- dist(x)
hc_row <- hclust(dst)
row_dend <- as.dendrogram(hc_row)
row_dend <- seriate_dendrogram(row_dend, dst, method="OLO")

# The dendrogram for columns
dst <- dist(t(x))
hc_row <- hclust(dst)
col_dend <- as.dendrogram(hc_row)
col_dend <- seriate_dendrogram(col_dend, dst, method="OLO")
col_dend <- rotate(col_dend, order = rev(labels(dst)[get_order(as.hclust(col_dend))]))

# The pheatmap with the same clustering of heatmaply
pheatmap(x, cluster_rows=as.hclust(row_dend), cluster_cols=as.hclust(col_dend))
```

The output of `heatmaply`
[image]

and the output of `pheatmap`
[image]